# Refactor code to break links so Variant type is not used

Tags: vba, excel

How do I refactor the following sub-routine so it does not use the Variant data type?

```
Sub BreakAllLinks()

Dim Link As Variant
Dim myLinks As Variant

myLinks = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=Excel.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
For Each Link In myLinks
    Excel.ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=Link, Type:=Excel.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next Link

End Sub
```

Comment: As for `myLinks`, the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821922(v=office.15).aspx) says it returns a `Variant` so I'm not sure you can re-factorize that one. As for the second, you might add a watcher to the variable (the casted type will appear on the right-side column).

Comment: I agree with Matteo's first point.  A For-Each control variable must be an object or a variant.  You could change to `For InxLink = LBound(myLinks) to UBound(myLinks)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with no Variants - but you shouldn't.

```
Sub BreakAllLinks()

    Dim myLinks() As String
    Dim LinkIdx As Long
    Dim Link As String

    ReDim myLinks(1 To UBound(ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)))

    For LinkIdx = LBound(myLinks) To UBound(myLinks)
        myLinks(LinkIdx) = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)(LinkIdx)
    Next LinkIdx

    For LinkIdx = LBound(myLinks) To UBound(myLinks)
        Link = myLinks(LinkIdx)
        ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next LinkIdx

End Sub
```

That's a little over-the-top on purpose to demonstrate all the data types involved.  You can only For..Each an array with a Variant - it's just how the language is written. The best practice isn't 'don't use Variants' but rather 'Use the most restrictively typed variable that you can'. In your case, the Variant is the most restrictively typed variable you can use.

There is a way to write that without Variants and not so obviously crazy

```
Sub BreakAllLinks()

    Dim LinkIdx As Long

    For LinkIdx = LBound(ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(1)) To UBound(ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(1))
        ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(1)(1), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next LinkIdx

End Sub
```

But even then, I'd opt for the Variant. It's worth the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

A Linksource is a String.
But why bother ?

```
Sub M_snb()
  For Each it In ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(1)
    MsgBox = TypeName(it)
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink it, 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Since `it` is a variant here how does it address the question? (I agree with the 'why bother' part though)

Comment: @Rory "why bother" in this case not a big deal, but best practice to use variant type as little as possible.

Comment: @snb unsure why your answer has been marked down - I've upped it back to zero.

Comment: That was me, for the reason I mentioned. The `it` variable here is a `Variant` so I didn't see the relevance of the answer.